# Create geospatial and type index together in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial, 2dsphere

I want to use two indexes from different index types (2dsphere and text) by using this command :

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({"@geolocationable":"2dsphere",name:"text"})
```

but I get the following Error:

> "errmsg" : "bad index key pattern { @geolocationable: \"2dsphere\",
>   name: \"text\" }: Can't use more than one index plugin for a single
>   index."

I read [MongoDB Text and 2D compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968671/mongodb-text-and-2d-compound-index)
but I'm not sure that why I can't create 2dsphere and text index in one collection.

I don't mean that I want to use of both indexes in one query while I want to create this indexes in order to use from them in separate queries individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Modified to answer the updated question.

If both the fields are to be used in queries separately, then you can create 2 different indexes instead of the compound index.

The geospatial index:

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({"@geolocationable":"2dsphere"})
```

The text index:

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({name:"text"})
```

Also, from [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) note that

> A collection can have at most one text index.

While creating a compound index, text index can not be grouped with a multi or geospatial index. It is a compound index restriction.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index):

> A compound text index cannot include any other special index types,
>   such as multi-key or geospatial index fields.

However, if you are not going to perform case insensitive searches on `name` field, you can create the compound index with a normal index instead of a text index.

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({"@geolocationable":"2dsphere",name:1})
```

Comment: I've updated the question I don't want to use of both indexes in one query

Comment: @Mobin: Updated my answer